# Sending jQuery ajax request on keyboard input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm sending an ajax request to the server on user's input to an `<input>` element, like this:

```
$('#my-input').bind("input", function(event){
   // here's the ajax request
});
```

What bothers me is that it send unnecessarily many requests on **every** user's keyup, meaning that if the user types very fast, there are many unnecessary requests. So I get the idea that there should be a certain delay/timeout, which waits a certain time (50 miliseconds?) for the user to stop typing before sending the ajax request. That would be one problem solved.

But what about cases when the first ajax request haven't been completed before sending another request? (Typing 60 ms / char while ajax request taking 300 ms).

What is the best way to solve this problem (both idea- and code-based)?

Comment: Are you trying to capture every key stroke, or would you prefer to just capture the end message (blur)?

Comment: @sgeddes: I don't want every capture, I want the end message, BUT there is no blur at the end (the user doesn't have to unclick the area).

Comment: is only capturing enter an option? or ignoring backspace - don't know if that will actually helpmuch though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [throttle](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#throttle) function in underscore library. As its documentation says:

> Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.

Even if you don't want to introduce a new library, you can still get idea about how this function works from its [source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html). In fact, a simple version of `throttle` function could be:

```
function throttle(func, delay) {
    var timeout = null;
    return function() {
        var that = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            func.apply(that, args);
        }, delay);
    };
}
```

This jQuery [throttle-debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) is also helpful. Especially, the `debounce` function seems more suitable to your needs than `throttle` function according to its author:

> Debouncing can be especially useful for rate limiting execution of handlers on events that will trigger AJAX requests

Comment: I don't think this is the best way to solve this problem. The library seems very unnecessary to me.

Comment: If you use JS intensively, this library is your good friend. Anyway, you can just get code snippet from its source.

Comment: But why introduce a new library when setTimeout is available with jQuery?  Throttling doesn't seem appropriate for this scenario...

Comment: @sgeddes First, `setTimeout` is JS built-in function, not jQuery-specific. Secondly, as I said, you don't have to introduce new library, that function implementation is not long, just copy&paste. Lastly, I updated my answer and suggested another library, where `debounce` may be more suitable than `throttle`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the setTimeout function.  Every so often, see if the text hasn't changed, and if it hasn't, then process accordingly.

```
setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 1 second
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yes, this solves the first part of the problem, but not the overlaying ajax requests.

Comment: That may be something you'll have to resolve server-side.  Queue up the requests before submitting to the db.  Several different implementations out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set async: false in your ajax request so it will process second ajax call only after completion of first ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with [@HuiZeng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290516/1177441), but just in case you want a slightly modified version.

Steps

1. Listen to keydown using a setTimeout that you can clear.
2. When it fires, check if you have a previous request in queue, if so abort it and fire a new one

Example:

```
var inputTimer = 0, req;

function onInput(e){
      clearTimeout(inputTImer);
      inputTimer = setTimeout( function(){
           // You have access to e here
           // Cancel any previous requests
           req && req.abort();
           req = $.ajax({/*...Do your magic here :)*/})
      }, 100)
 }
```